# Error: ClerkJS: Invalid frontendAPI option. Go to the instance home page at https://dashboard.clerk.dev and get your Frontend API value

Tags: javascript, authentication, npm, next.js, clerk

ClerkJS API will not work even though I have inserted the correct Clerk API keys.

I am expecting for the application to allow me to use the ClerkJS API for user authentication.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use `publishableKey` instead `frontendApi`. Docs [here](https://clerk.com/docs/reference/clerk-react/clerkprovider). Works for my Gatsby + Netlify website.

```
<ClerkProvider
  publishableKey={clerk_pub_key}
  navigate={to => navigate(to)}
>
  Your application tree goes here.
  <SignedIn>
    <UserButton />
  </SignedIn>
</ClerkProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and I think it was caused because I had added the ENV variables after my site was deployed.

To fix this, I redeployed my most recent deployment and then everything worked.